# Are there Example for InsideOut Design and Clustering of Collections in Android

Tags: android, horizontallist

I saw in [DevBytes Android 4.4: Collectons](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r6jMnYwjftk#t=2175) the possiblility to have a StaggeredGridLayout which will handle a dynamic adding/removing of Items. Its possible to fill the items in a vertical order, till you have no space anymore, and then continue on the next column, whithout knowing the amount of items when specifing the layout.

Im looking for a view , which will look like the Android Play Market, but its size expands horizontally, it should just contain simple squared items, like cards.

Example:

[1, 4,..,.., n*Y+1, (n+1)*Y+1]

[2, 5,..,..,n*Y+2, (n+2)*Y+1]

[3, 6,..,..,n*Y+3, empty]

[Y,2Y,..,..,n*Y+Y, empty]

Somehow, it should be a horizontal List, where i can put in each item a vertical List fitting as much items as needed to fill the screen. but i think thats pretty awful to implement and to maintain all elements/items.

The Problem with GridLayout is that i need to know the amount of Items in advance. I was searching the hole day for sth. but i couldnt find anything similiar to which fits my needs.